# Can't open bitcoin-qt GUI on Raspberry Pi

Tags: bitcoin-core, raspberry-pi, bitcoincore-gui

I installed the latest bitcoin node on my Raspberry Pi 4 following this guide:
https://www.makeuseof.com/bitcoin-node-raspberry-pi/
Everything went well, only the last step where you need to start the GUI I get an error message.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /usr/local/bin/bitcoin-qt
/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-qt: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I googled the issue and found a thread here on the same problem.
[How do I run GUI on Raspbian?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57209/how-do-i-run-gui-on-raspbian)

I downloaded all dependencies from the github page, but still the same issue.

I went to the file manager and indeed I found no such file or directory (/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-qt).
I do find it somewhere else:
[image]

But how do I open it from this place in the terminal?
If I type /home/pi/bitcoin-0.21.1/bin/bitcoin-qt I get the same error.

The following I find in the instructions for installing the node on bitcoin.org:
[image]

But libfontconfig1 is installed and is the newest version.

Comment: Which file did you download? You may have installed the 64-bit library but are using 32-bit binaries, so there may be compatibility issues.

Comment: I downloaded the bitcoin core installer for ARM linux 64-32 bit. There's only one file to download and install. The Raspberry Pi has the 64 bit OS image installed. Can I still be using 32 bit binaries? How can I check and change this?

Comment: There is a link to the 64-bit binary under the "ARM linux" icon, it's the thing that says "64 bit". Try using that.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I missed that :)